# Как защитить программу от распространения

Tags: android

Есть apk-файл, приложение Android, нужно что-то придумать, чтобы сделать какую-нибудь защиту от его распространения.

Я передаю этот apk одному лицу и не хочу, чтобы у него была возможность распространить этот apk кому-то ещё. Нужно чтобы он мог установить это приложение только на свой телефон и не смог его передать кому-либо.

Может быть написать какую-то программу-установщик, при входе в неё будет требоваться какой-нибудь код (может одноразовый), а только потом появляется возможность установки того самого apk (который можно вшить в эту программу-установщик). Либо при входе в программу-установщик сначала происходит проверка какого нибудь ID телефона (или google id), если все норм, то может начаться установка самого АПК приложения (который и пытаемся защитить).

Может быть идея не самая лучшая, но единственное что пока приходит на ум.

Comment: Первым делом нужно подумать про сильную обсуфкацию приложения, потому что иначе все ваши проверки можно будет просто пропатчить

Comment: И потом вынести проверку по ключу, например, и каким-то id телефона в нативную либу

Comment: Рекламный айди может меняться.

Answer (score 0):

Установщики не помогут, ведь потом апк можно скачать с телефона.

Можно сделать авторизацию через аккаунт телефона и передавать айди на сервер. На сервере банить предпоследний айди. По этой проверке блокировать интерфейс.

Comment: Есть ньюанс, что исходников от этой программы не осталось. Только АПК. Соответственно и вносить изменения в код программы нет возможности. Да, с установщиком получается не очень надёжно, но хоть какая то защита от чайников есть. Если рассматривать этот вариант с установщиком, подскажите, как можно это реализовать?

Comment: @Alexander, да любой чайник достанет ваш APK после установки - приложения, которые это делают можно скачать прямо с гугло-маркета. Сколько-нибудь надёжную защиту можно сделать только в самом приложении.

Comment: Если нет исходников, что можно придумать?

Comment: Осваивать реверс-инжиниринг, наверное. Заодно получите полезный опыт и в самом реверсе, и в том как от него защититься.

Comment: @woesss написать клон программы проще)

Comment: Осваивать реверс-инжиниринг/писать клон - время, которого у меня нет. Нужно по-быстрому что-то сварганить. Если брать вариант с установщиком, то правильно заметили, что даже чайник сможет вытащить установленные АПК на телефоне. А если написать установщик и чтобы запуск нужной программы (которую и защищаем) был непосредственно через установщик, и в меню телефона была иконка только установщика. Возможно ли такое?

Comment: без пересборки апк невозможно

Comment: Всё равно нужно модифицировать приложение, чтобы оно не запускалось без установщика. Тогда уже лучше внедрить защиту в само приложение.

Comment: @woesss можно попробовать чисто на манифесте главное активити сломать, а с внешнего приложения запускать его на прямую

Comment: Но это уже реверс - нужно декомпилировать манифест, изменить, скомпиллировать, заменить в APK, APK "выровнять" и подписать.

Comment: @eri вы не могли бы оставить свою почту? Один вопрос есть

Comment: Я не умею реверсить апк, просто знаю куда можно копнуть)

Comment: @eri жаль, я бы достойно отблагодарил)

Comment: Достойно это 120к₽. Но за 120 можно написать новое приложение(кроме игрушек)

Comment: @eri ну за такую сумму вы должны как минимум уметь реверсить апк

Comment: 120к₽ за одну консультацию? Где-то на фоне всплакнула Блиновская)))

Comment: Есть такая штука APK Multi Tool, кажется - она прям для чайников, инструкцию освоите за гораздо меньшее время, чем потратили на общение с нами). С её помощью вы получите папку с декомпилированными ресурсами и кодом в smali. Сможете поправить манифест и, при желании код, и собрать обратно в APK. Задача минимум - убрать из манифеста фильтр MAIN/LAUNCHER - без него приложение нельзя будет запустить обычным способом, ярлыков для запуска не будет.

Comment: Но, как не сложно догадаться, - таким же способом и с такой же лёгкостью всё можно вернуть обратно.

Comment: @woesss спасибо. По поводу того, что это можно обратно вернуть - я не волнуюсь, потому что и не надеюсь на сверх надёжную защиту. Категория человека, которому может понадобится мой АПК, находится в районе чуть выше чайника. Может вы скинете почту? один вопрос есть.

Answer (score 0):

Не существует никакого способа, позволяющего полностью избежать этого.

> По сути, вы не можете защитить свое приложение от изменений или распространения. И любую
> установленную вами защиту можно отключить/удалить.

В вашем же случае защититься практически нереально, с отсутствием исходников вы не сможете этого сделать этого быстро (если вообще сможете).

Comment: Да, я понимаю это, поэтому и не надеюсь на сверх надёжную защиту своей программы. Но нужна хоть какая то)